# Download pdf vuejs from API Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, vuejs2

hello I have a frontend with VUEJS and backend Laravel 5.4.
I would download a pdf saved in **storage/folder/file.pdf**

Now I make a ajax call from VUEJS:

```
downloadAttachment(){
                axios.get('/url/attachment/' + this.resource.id)
                    .then(function (response) {

                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {

                    });
                }
```

and in backend I have a function that return pdf file:

```
public function download(){
  $headers = array(
                    'Content-Type: application/pdf'
                );
  return response()->download(storage_path('folder/file.pdf'), 'namefile.pdf' , $headers)->setStatusCode(200);
}
```

But now How Can i show an Iframe for download in frontend?

I tried with:

```
var blob = new Blob([response.data],{type:headers['content-type']});
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = "Filename";
link.click();
```

But it doesn't work, How can i show in frontend iframe with pdf file download?

Comment: Why do you need an iframe ? I just use `window.location.href = '/url/attachment/' + this.resource.id`

Comment: thankyou for reply, because it is an API and I would directly file to download and not a redirect.

Comment: Your API is returning a file download, the browser's behaviour in that case is to download the file and not actually redirect. Just make sure the content disposition is being set correctly.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this with ajax instead of just an anchor element?

Comment: yes, I need an ajax call and not redirect because It should return a json. 
if I haven't permission it should return json error, instead return  file if I have permission, with redirect and an error I see a white page with json

Comment: Reconsider this approach. It's far easier to send an AJAX request asking the server if you can download the link and then using a simple window.location if the server responds that you're allowed. Using iframe adds unnecessary complexity

Comment: ok, so the right approach is send from backend the url of file if I have permission and then windows.location if I understand well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `window.open(URL)`.

Here the "URL" should be the actual URL string so **probably** you will have to change the response of the controller to something like: `return response()->json(<url string>)`